# Works without maven profile, bug with

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-profiles

Here is my problem,

So here is my profile in pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>dev</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>environment</name>
                    <value>prod</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

When I use this context.xml, my application works perfectly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:jd="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3-0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="net.xxx.xxx.dao" />       

  <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:essmh" />
            <property name="username" value="*****" />
            <property name="password" value="*****" />
      </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="carfleetPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />    
</beans>
```

But I want to be able to change my `dataSource` according if I'm in production or in development.

So here is what I've got now:

```
 <beans profile="dev">
  <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521:dev" />
            <property name="username" value="*****" />
            <property name="password" value="*****" />
      </bean>   
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
  <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1522:prod" />
            <property name="username" value="*****" />
            <property name="password" value="*****" />
      </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="dev, prod">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="carfleetPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I check by using `mvn -e -P prod help:active-profiles` that the profile `prod` is active in every package and it is. But at the end, it doesn't work and I get the Error :

`Caused by : org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException : No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0.`

For sure the error is there, because that's the only changed to go from "application is working" to "application has errors".

---

**EDIT**

I now understand that I confused Spring profile and Maven profile, but I still, want to link the 2 of them.
So for this, I put properties in my pom.xml > profiles :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties> 
                <environment>dev</environment> 
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties> 
                <environment>prod</environment> 
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

And I add in my web.xml :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
<param-value>${environment}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

When I hardcode `${environment}` for `dev` or `prod` it works perfectly.
But when I want to be able to switch from Maven : `clean -Pprod  package tomcat7:redeploy`
I got the following issue :

```
IllegalArgumentException : Could not resolve placeholder 'environment' in string value "${environment}`
```

Comment: same error, with or without the space :/

Comment: Are you sure that maven profile and Spring profile is the same thing?

Comment: I'm not sure at all :/ how can I check that ?

Comment: i think the problem here is that you didn't set spring.profiles.active property in your project and the spring framework cannot find bean with name EntityManagerFactory because this bean is either in dev or in prod profile but you actually don't set active profile in the project. you are only setting maven property named "environment"

Comment: It's probably this, because every answer seems to agree with that :/ but how to fix this :/

Comment: Could you provide web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using web.xml you can set context-param property which will point to your current env. First try to hardcode this tag.

```
<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
<param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml config to check if everything will work fine, then try to set your own variable with current environment.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420745/how-to-set-spring-active-profiles-with-maven-profiles) for more help.

Comment: It's indeed working by hardcoding it.

So now the problem is : how to be able to switch this with the command line of Maven :/

Comment: Use the maven profile name here i.e. ${environment}

Comment: I'm probably stupid in this field, but I run maven with : `mvn -e clean -Denvironment=prod package tomcat7:redeploy` and I get the error : `Could not resolve placeholder 'environment' in string value "${environment}. :/ 
It's not supposed to be done like this ?

Comment: you are not stupid ! when i was reading about profiles in maven and spring was confused too.  try to add properties not in <activation> tag, but in <profile> tag like this: `<!-- Dev Env. Properties -->
<properties>
 <environment>dev</environment>
</properties>`

Comment: Otherwise , in Tomcat server  add the System Property with name as 'spring.profiles.active' and value should be 'dev' or 'prod'. Then you don't need to hardcode in web.xml

Comment: See the EDIT of what I've done and what is the error :/

Comment: Ok I find myself the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566267/maven-how-to-fill-a-variable-in-web-xml-file. Thanks all guys for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing maven profiles and spring profiles! Those are different things.
You can use

```
spring.profiles.active
```

to enable the profile that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to EDIT : [Maven: how to fill a variable in web.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566267/maven-how-to-fill-a-variable-in-web-xml-file)

The plugin `maven-war-plugin` need some configuration, to be able to make a filter on the Descriptors of the Spring profile.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With all this, you can switch from Maven profile to Spring profile. Thank you all guys for your help :).